# How to execute 2 commands through one button press in a windows 8 app

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-8

Here is my button:

```
<Button x:Name="PassInspectionButton" Style="{StaticResource LikeAppBarButtonStyle}" 
Command="{Binding PassInspectionCommand}"/>
```

Here is my viewmodel code:

```
public ICommand PassInspectionCommand { get; private set; }

public void PassInspection()
{
    SelectedInspection.Status = "Pass";
    //GoBackCommand.Execute(); << This is the second command I want to execute
}

private void Initialize()
{
    PassInspectionCommand = new DelegateCommand(PassInspection);
}
```

So Basically my button updates my Status to "Pass", but then I want it to automatically go back a page.
My GoBackCommand will detect the previous page and go back to it.  If I bind my button's command to "GoBackCommand" it will go back a page.  If I bind it to "PassInspectionCommand", it will set Status to "Pass"

I can't figure out a way to get the button to set the Status to "Pass" and then immediately go back a page.

I am trying to execute the ICommand "GoBackCommand" inside of my ICommand "PassInspectionCommand", but it doesn't like that either because Execute needs a parameter that I have no idea what to put in there.

Thanks ahead of time for any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Okra framework](http://okra.codeplex.com/) to get a useful built-in navigation system. Then call:

```
GoBackCommand.Execute(null);
```